# p:rowExpansion not showing values in some cases (JSF+Primefaces application)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF+Primefaces 3.2 application.
I am using p:rowExpansion within a p:dataTable.
In some cases it works great but for some records it doesn't show any records.

```
<p:dataTable id="accountTable" value="#{accountBean.accountList}" var="account" 
rows ="10" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" widgetVar="accountTable">
    <f:facet name="header">
    </f:facet>
    <p:column>
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{account.shortName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column  headerText="#{msj.account_accountNumber}">
        <h:outputText value="#{account.number}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:rowExpansion>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msj.detail} #{account.shortName} - #{account.number}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msj.account_shortName}:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{account.shortName}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msj.account_accountNumber}:"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{account.number}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msj.account_currency}:"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{account.currency.code} - #{account.currency.description}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

It is wierd, because the same value that is shown in the datatable (account.shortName) is not shown in the expansion area.

I have another datatable (just like this) in the same page. Debugging with firebug I realize that it is refreshing the other datatable, and sending the request as if I were pressing the Row expandion of the other datatable.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the same widgetVar name across the tables.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? I believe I recall a similar bug listed a while ago. If you aren't already there, try upgrading to 3.2.

Comment: I edited the question with more info. Please check.

Comment: That is strange. Any chance of a copy/paste error? Maybe the same widgetVar name across the tables?

Comment: That was the problem, widgetVar! Thank you very much